# Whitelist json and php

Tags: php, json, whitelist

I am making a userid whitelist in php and json but it wont work so it should be like this

```
{ "users": { "ANID": { "ANID": "true" }, 
"97594568": { "isvalid": "true" }, 
"ANID": { "isvalid": "true" }, 
"ANID": { "isvalid": "true" }, 
"ANID": { "isvalid": "true" }, 
"ANID": { "isvalid": "true" }, 
"ANID": { "isvalid": "true" } } }
```

**and if** you go to whitelist.php?uid=ANID it should say succes and if not whitelisted it should say Failed

Comment: Could you share some PHP code you've tried?

Comment: <?php
$data = file_get_contents ("aser.json");
        $json = json_decode($data, true);
       if status = active then {
        foreach ($json as $key => $value) {
            if (!is_array($value)) {
                echo $key . '=>' . $value . '<br/>';
            } else {
                foreach ($value as $key => $val) {
                    echo $key . '=>' . $val . '<br/>';
                }
            }
        }

?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`array_key_exists`](http://php.net/array_key_exists):

**whitelist.json:**

```
{
  "users": {
    "0001": {
      "isvalid": "true"
    },
    "0002": {
      "isvalid": "true"
    },
    "0003": {
      "isvalid": "true"
    },
    "0004": {
      "isvalid": "true"
    },
    "0005": {
      "isvalid": "true"
    }
  }
}
```

**whitelist.php**

```
<?php

$data = file_get_contents('whitelist.json');
$json = json_decode($data, true);

if (array_key_exists($_GET['uid'], $json['users'])) {
    echo 'User is whitelisted';
} else {
    echo 'User is NOT whitelisted';
}
```

`whitelist.php?uid=0001` would return `User is whitelisted`

`whitelist.php?uid=0006` would return `User is NOT whitelisted`

Comment: it works ty u helped me alot

Comment: If my answer solved your question, accept it as the answer by clicking the tick